# C# ASP.NET TSQL Code Behind Upgrade DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade the db from users' input, but it doesn't work...

I'm using this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand ncmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utenti Set Nome = @vnome where [Indirizzo E-Mail]=@vem", con);
    ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vem", Session["[Indirizzo E-Mail]"].ToString());
    ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vnome", TextBox2.Text);
    ncmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    ncmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label2.Text = "Dati aggiornati con successo!";
    Response.Redirect("~/ModificaDati.aspx");
}
```

When I click on the button it show me the Label2 text, but in the database the "Nome" is not changed, why?
Thanks before for the answers ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your method as below

```
if (Session["[Indirizzo E-Mail]"] != null &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["[Indirizzo E-Mail]"].ToString()) &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
{
    string vem = Session["[Indirizzo E-Mail]"].ToString(); 
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    using (var ncmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utenti Set Nome = @vnome where [Indirizzo E-Mail]=@vem", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vem", vem);
        ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vnome", TextBox2.Text);
        int rows  = ncmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label2.Text = rows  + " Dati aggiornati con successo!";
    }
}

Response.Redirect("~/ModificaDati.aspx");
```

1. Added input validation, session values can be null, better to check before you update database
2. when you create `SqlCommand` you can give the connection, no need to set it again
3. make sure your SQL is valid
4. use `using` statements for disposable objects like `SqlConnection, SqlCommand`

Comment: Now i see "1 Dati aggiornati con successo!"

Comment: @DanieleNekoLuciani that `1` means one row updated successfully in the database.

Comment: But in the database there is not this update! The name remains "Daniele" as before, and I've put "Clorinda"

Comment: are you check correct database? can you give the connection string?

Comment: Sorry for late. However now it goes! I had wrong a command before of our method ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Just make sure you check if SQL is correct as Damith already suggested.

Another thing I’s recommend is additionally validating your parameters for data type correctness before executing the query. 
Using this approach you’ll probably avoid a lot of unnecessary exceptions and also be able to provide more user friendly messages. Of course this only applies if user input is non text type

```
//Data Type verification
DateTime tmp;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(Label2.Text.Trim(), out tmp))
{ 
  //Show error message that this is not a correct data type
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your connection first

con.Open();

ncmd.Connection = con;

Hope it helps